# Building a presentation video

Tags: video

Hi everyone I am in my last three days before I present my final project for my exam at college everything is ready for the final presentation except a good presentation.At first I made one in Microsoft Power Point but it isn't very cool looking.

I just got an idea for the presentation to create a video that slide's diferent images that containing information about my project , add some music in the background and at some point the music's volume will be turned lower and and mp3 with me talking will start playing.

Until now it isn't something I could not do in power point aldo I hope you guys will suggest another software because I also want to add over the presentation practicly another video with me that is talking and pointing my hand on different subjects from the video.I have never done this before and do not know how am I supose to cut that part with me talking from one video and add it over another.

Can anyone suggest a good easy to learn software that can achive this and has an easy learning curve?And also some tutorials on that.Can a beginner like me manage to do it in 3 days?

This would be an example of what I would like to make:

[example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jZ_Ns3Sqqo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example provided by @hasanyasin looks more like an impress.js presentation, whose code and examples you can reach [**right here**](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored)

The impress.js includes some easy to edit examples on which you can easily embed images (both static or animated), videos, audio, etc. You don't need to have advanced skills to create a pro-like presentation.

Anyway, what you wish to do in a video can be achieved by a professional non linear editing system, like Sony Vegas or Adobe Premiere, of which Sony Vegas is the easiest to learn.

If you are used to Microsoft Based Products (PhotoShop, Corel Draw, Office, Movie Maker, etc.) you are almost ready to do it.

The process to place you in front of the moving images, videos, transitions, text and other media is called "Chroma Key" and it can be reached in the Effects tab of the Sony Vegas 8 (and previous/further versions). A video tutorials on how to create the Chroma Key effect can be found on youtube by dropping the terms "chroma key sony vegas", here is an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMgxQCwfrcs

Basically you work in multi layer. Placing in a time line the elements in the order that you wish them to appear on screen, adding a background, in/out transitions, and other elements. Remember that the top layer will be the "front" element on screen. After which you insert your blue/green screen video at the very top, apply the Chroma Key effect, choose the dropper and select the background in your video, after which you adjust the threshold in order not to appear like a ghost in the video.

You will need to use the "Event Pan and Crop" tool in order to create the "moving" effect for some static items, like pictures and even if you wish your videos to "fly" around the screen. Just run a search in youtube with the words "Pan and Crop Sony Vegas" and you will get tons of results. Here is an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpvJ6Dhz63M

And yes...  you can create awesome results in a couple of hours. Give it a try and drop us back a link with your published video.

Good luck!

Comment: My example looks more like a Prezi presentation than an impress.js presentation. :) I mean the original idea that impress.js was built on was of Prezi's. What I use is not impress.js; but Inkscape which is much easier than doing it in impress.js since it is an advanced vector application with a GUI, good or bad, it is more likely to be an alternative to PowerPoint than impress.js until the gui work on at least one of the projects reaches to a usable state... As for timeline, I really don't know which one precedes others; but I had known Sozi much before I saw impress.js on github.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/hasanyasin/stackoverflow/p-0-nofont.svg

Every modern browser should render it correctly. You can navigate with arrow keys and zoom in/out via mouse wheel or Ctrl and +/- keys.

It is made on [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) using [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/en%3ainstall) extension. If you like what you see it is very easy to do. I believe it is pretty cool.

Be careful though. Do not spend too much time on visuals. The real thing that will bring you success is the content. Even if you have created a great project, telling it well is another story. Don't let these things distract you from the real target: presenting your project as clearly and effective as possible. Visuals is just makeup and if face is beautiful in its natural state, makeup may just add a little touch, nothing beyond that. On the other hand, extreme or inappropriate use of it can make a beautiful face look so ugly, even disturbing.

I hope your presentation will be very successful. :)

UPDATE: Sorry that I forgot my first paragraph when I searched and uploaded the file I wanted to give as an example. A presentation, if you will be there, is not good as a video. You are 1000x more lively than a video, always. Let the presentation stay behind and do the talking live. Maybe your environment is totally different than how I imagine this in my mind; but switching from a PowerPoint presentation to a video with music sounds a little too much. I hope I am not being too much too. Please accept this as humble views of an old plain man.

UPDATE2: After seeing your edit, I see you are decided about putting yourself in video. The guy in that example was shot in front of a "Green Screen" and then cut from background on software. For Green Screen, make a search for "Green Screen Tips" or similar things and you will see it is not 3 days business. And I know it looks really cool to you now; but believe me, if everybody else is making PowerPoint presentations and you go put there a video and expect others to watch it and say "wow it is awesome" maybe your friends will say it; but your professors will not. It is the best when you are there. That guy in that video would prefer being here and talking to me face to face. He made that video because he cannot come and talk to me face to face. Putting a video there and hiding aside will not make you look good. It will make you look asocial and amateur.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to switch to an overview and then select a slide in the svg presentation, or am I missing something?